# pandas to_sql in django: insert foreign key into DB

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys, django-database, django-postgresql, pandas-to-sql

**Is there a way to insert foreign keys when using pandas to_sql function?**

I am processing uploaded `Consultation`s (n=40k) with pandas in django, before adding them to the database (postgres). I got this working row by row, but that takes 15 to 20 minutes. This is longer than I want my users to wait, so I am looking for a more efficient solution.

I tried pandas to_sql, but I cannot figure out how to add the two foreign key relations as columns to my `consultations` dataframe before calling the `to_sql` function. Is there a way to add the Patient and Praktijk foreign keys as a column in the `consultations` dataframe?

More specifically, when inserting row by row, I use objects of **type** `Patient` or `Praktijk` when creating new consultations in the database. In a dataframe however, I cannot use these types, and therefore don't know how I could add the foreign keys correctly. Is there possibly a value of type `object` or `int` (a patient's id?) which can substitute a value of type Patient, and thereby set the foreign key?

The `Consultation` model:

```
class Consultation(models.Model):
    # the foreign keys
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    praktijk = models.ForeignKey(Praktijk, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')

    # other fields which do not give trouble with to_sql
    patient_nr = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # etc
```

The `to_sql` call:

```
consultations.to_sql(Consult._meta.db_table, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

If above is not possible, any hints towards another more efficient solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and this is how I solved it. My answer isn't as straight forward but I trust it helps.

Inspect your django project to be sure of two things:

1. Target table name
2. Table column names

In My case, I use `class Meta` when defining django models to use explicit name (django has a way of automatically naming tables). I will use [django tutorial project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/) to illustrate.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    class Meta:
        db_table = "poll_questions"

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "question_choices"
```

Note: *Django references Question foreign key in the database using **pk** of the Question object.*

Assume I have a Question pk 1, and a dataframe **df** that I wish to update Question choices with. **My df must look like one below if using pandas to batch insert into database!**

```
import pandas as pd  

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "question": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "choice_text": [
            "First Question",
            "Second Question",
            "Third Question",
            "Fourth Question",
            "Fifth Question"
        ],
        "votes":[5,3,10,1,13]
    }
)
```

*I wish I could write the df as a table. Too bad that SO doesn't support usual markdown for tables*

Nonetheless, we have our df next step is to create database connection for inserting the records.

```
from django.conf import settings
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# load database settings from django

user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
passwd = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
dbname = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']

# create database connection string
conn = 'postgresql://{user}:{passwd}@localhost:5432/{dbname}'.format(
    user=user,
    passwd=passwd,
    dbname=dbname
)

# actual database connection object.
conn = create_engine(conn, echo=False)

# write df into db
df.to_sql("question_choices", con=conn, if_exists="append", index=False, chunksize=500, method="multi")
```

**Voila!**
We are done!

Note:
django supports [bulk-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) which, however, isn't what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using SQLalchemy but I found a simple workaround.

What I did is defined the database schema the way I wanted with SQLalchemy (with all the datatypes and foreign keys I needed) and then created an empty table, then I simply changed the `if_exists` parameter to `append`.

This will append all the data to an empty database.